# How to reset HTTPHEADERs in pycurl object?

Tags: python, pycurl

I've set some additional headers using

```
c.setopt(self.c.HTTPHEADER, ['Accept: */*', ..., ...])
```

Now what I want is to reset/clear that headers without destroying pycurl object or closing session.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this easily with:

```
c.reset()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset a header setting its value to blank string

```
                        #   erase 2 headers and keep others
c.setopt(self.c.HTTPHEADER, ["User-Agent:","Accept:"])
```